# Content div within flushing right

Tags: css, html

I designed my friend's website using a container `div` to center the content with multi `div`s within. Everything looked fine and all the `div`s looked vertically aligned in Dreamweaver "view." However, once I uploaded everything, the "content" `div` is somehow flushed left to the rest of the content.

I'm really frustrated and don't know where the code is going wrong.

Here's the css: http://tmaniatv.com/home.css
Here's the site: [tmaniatv.com](http://tmaniatv.com)

EDIT: So far I've been able to flush it left, but only as temp workaround (`margin-right:-200px;`)

Comment: You probably mean 'floated' - but when I try, that website has perfectly centered content. Tried Firefox and IE9.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of how you want the page to look?

Comment: please provide more information

Comment: Want to look how it does now: but without workaround, looks like below
Without fix: http://tmaniatv.com/test.html
http://tmaniatv.com/new.css

Answer (score 1):

I see your issue. Remove the margin:-200px; from your content div, then move that content div and its container **out** of the nav container. Your content div is simply floating inside your nav :)

Your code should be structured as follows:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">...header content..</div>
        <div id="nav">...nav content..</div>
        <div id="content">...move me!..</div>
        <div id="footer">...move me too!..</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tested it, and this fixes it.

Comment: Dear Juan T, thanks for looking at this. I tried this and it broke - and I checked to see that the div closing tags were in the right position. So, I switched it back to margin-right: -200px;

Comment: Heres a paste bin with the updated HTML. Try grabbing all of it and replacing your test html. http://jsbin.com/inezok/1/